# Istio VirtualServie with DaemonSet on hostPort

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a DaemonSet exposed via hostPort. Is it possible to create a istio VirtualService that points to hostIP:hostPort?

Answer (score 0):

Istio VirtualService is a set of traffic routing rules.

Based on the matching criteria, traffic is sent to destination **service** but **NOT hostIP**

So, with VirtualService you can set a combination of service name and NodePort

```
- destination:
        host: my-service.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 9080
```

What is the background of your request? Probably it can be achieved in some other way.